# Visible Frame of NSScreen is too large

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, applescript

I need the bounds of my screen to know the smallest and biggest x / y coordinates. My screen resolution is 1440x900. When I ask NSScreen for the visible frame, i.e.

```
NSRect frame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame]
```

I get the following x / y values:

```
xMin = NSMinX(frame) // 74
yMin = NSMinY(frame) // 0
xMax = NSMaxX(frame) // 1440
yMax = NSMaxY(frame) // 878
```

I have the Dock on the left side, thus my xMin is larger 0 and yMin is 0. However, the problem is yMax. As far as I can tell, the menu bar is 44 pixel high, thus yMax should be 900 - 44 = 856 pixel. According to NSScreen the menu bar can at most use up 22 pixel. How is that?

---

More informations about my use case: I adjust window positions and window sizes via Applescript. To know which values are allowed, i.e. inside the visible frame, I need to check against NSScreen's visible frame. However, NSScreen starts counting pixels from the lower left, while Applescript starts from the upper left. In the process of building a method for NSScreen to return its coordinate from upper left, I came across this problem.

The transformed visible frame has an yMin of 22, thus 22 pixels from the upper bound. I experimented with Applescript directly and found out, that every yMin below 44 will be adjusted to be 44, since the menu bar occupies the space from 0 up to 43 pixel.

---

I hope my explanation was not too confusing. In the end the problem is that experiments show that the menu bar is 44 pixels high, while NSScreen only leaves 22 pixels free for the menu bar (since it's height is 878 pixels on an 900 pixel screen).

---

**EDIT:** The height of the menu bar *is* 22 pixel. It's a problem of the finder how he handles events concerning his bounds-property.

Comment: My menu bar is 22 pixels high (or something in that range). Definitely not 44.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu bar is 22 pixels. As a test open TextEdit, push its window to the top of the screen, and then run this applescript and you'll see it's 22.

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    bounds of window 1
end tell
```

The problem you're seeing is with how the Finder is measuring its windows. In 10.6 something changed. It seems the title bar of windows is not being accounted for by the Finder and thus the apparent 0 position of a window is not the upper left corner but some pixels down from that position. I also script window positions and notice that my code must differ between 10.5 and 10.6. As an example, open a Finder window and push it to the top of your screen, and then run this code... it shows 44.

```
tell application "Finder"
    bounds of window 1
end tell
```

To prove it's the Finder, run this script on the same Finder window. Notice the information from System Events versus the Finder. And remember, in 10.5 and earlier the Finder didn't show this discrepancy.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        set s to size of window 1
        set p to position of window 1
        return {p, s}
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: You are right, I used the "bounds"-property to set and read the position of the Finder window. The "size" and "position" properties work as intended, but require the accessibility option to be enabled.
However, I experimented with different applications myself and found out, that Xcode windows will start from the lower-left if the bounds-property is used and from the upper-left if the position/size-properties are used. Looks like I have to go with size/position ...